# Running a scheduler for mail once in a day for items created through asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

We are using an application in which, after `creating item`, a `mail` has been sent `every time`.
Now, I want it to be sent `once` in a day at `fix time` for all the items.
For example:-
at `18:00:00`, mail has to be sent to the `administrator` having details of all the items created.

Simply I mean to say that, mail has to be sent once in a day having details of all items created not all the time in a day when created but once in a fix time.

Comment: This can't be done in asp.net specifically. You need to write a console app to send email and create a scheduled task to run the exe at specific time or after certain duration.

Comment: I don't have any idea. Can you please explain with an example on how it can be done?

Comment: You have code ready for sending email to admin with the details? Please share that.